# Cannot access Apache web server from Wan side

Tags: apache2, port-forwarding

I am running apache 2.4.46 on parrot linux, I modified the default /var/www/html/index.html using html for educational purpose. I can access this server on LAN but I want to access this apache server on WAN, following some tutorials I port forwarded to inet 192.168.0.104 and port 80, I also used no-ip website to get a free dns and succesfully added it to my router. When I try to connect to this dns I get a 404 error. Can somebody help me to understand what I am missing.

ps ~ I after that removed the apache service and added ssh service on port 22 to check whether it was a dns mistake but I was successfully able to ssh into my computer over WAN

Comment: Try running your Apache on a different port. Port 80 may be used by your router's web management panel and it's possible that forwarding it will have no effect.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, 

I also tried different ports like 8080 and 443 still no success. Thank you

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are receiving a 404 then you know your Apache server is visible to the outside world. A 404 means the server received the request but can’t find a file. If the server were not accessible, you would see a timeout.

The most common cause of this issue is an incomplete Apache configuration. Check that you have a `ServerAlias` line in your `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` file (or whichever site config file is your target). The line can contain multiple routing targets for the Apache installation. For example:

```
ServerAlias example.com *.example.com
```

Generally what I do with these is have a catch all `*.*` thrown on the end so that any unexpected request routes, such as an IP address or bare CNAME address, gets handled without returning a 404 or 500 error.

Comment: Thanks for your respose :)
I edit the /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf with a line ServerAlias xxxx.ddns.net, I added the line under DocumentRoot /var/ww/html 

but still no success. 
Thank you

Comment: Have you restarted your Apache instance since making the changes? `sudo service apache2 restart`